# Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND

Tags: android, bluetooth, permissions, android-broadcast

I am trying to sendbroadcast. After execution, I get following error:

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND from pid=24885, uid=10370

If anyone has experience with this error, your kind help will be appreciated. Here is my method:

```
    private void DiscoverOBDConnection() {
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
final List<String> discoverableDevicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    intent=new Intent(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    String action = intent.getAction();
    // When discovery finds a device
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
      // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
      BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
      discoverableDevicesList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress() + "\n");
      String discoveredDeviceName = device.getName();
      }
    }
  }
};
mReceiver.onReceive(this, new Intent(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
```

}

manifest permissions:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"/>

Comment: Why would you *send* this action? It's sent by the system. And why are you overwriting the `intent` you receive in `onReceive()`?? Looks like very broken code.

Comment: I am new to android coding. Therefore, I  donot know the flow well enough. Do you have any idea how I get the list of discovered bluetooth devices?

Comment: I hope this helps you http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/android-example-bluetooth-discover-and.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

add admin permission to access bluetooth

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: using the same permission or some other issue?

Comment: I solved problem using another way. Instead of sending broadcast, I just registered my receiver. That was all. I'll share new method as soon as I go back to home. :)